# Primes Race (Mathematica Efficiency)

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, number-theory, prime-numbers

I am currently working with a paper that deals with this concept of Prime Races.  You essentially create a large list of prime numbers and then split that list into two teams.  You are assigned to team 1 if your remainder is 1 after being divided by 4.  You are assigned to team 2 if your remainder is 3.  You then choose an x value and see how many primes fall under that x value for each team.  It looks as though Team 1 always wins however there are certain cases this is not true.  For instance at x=26,861,  Team 1= 1472 while Team 2 = 1473.  I'm trying to expand x out to 1 million and find where this occurs at other places in a computational efficient way.  However the method I'm using takes forever.  Are there any other ideas or concepts that may work?

Here is my Mathematica code:

```
M = 100000;
listPrimes = Table[Prime[i], {i, 1, M}];
list1 = Select[listPrimes, Mod[#1, 4] == 3 &];
list2 = Select[listPrimes, Mod[#1, 4] == 1 &];
x = 26862;
list1cnt = Length[Select[list1, # <= x &]]
list2cnt = Length[Select[list2, # <= x &]]

mchk = 30000;
For[x = 26850, x <= mchk, x++,
  list1cnt = Length[Select[list1, # <= x &]];
  list2cnt = Length[Select[list2, # <= x &]];
  If[list2cnt > list1cnt, Print["Found One:", x]]
  ];
```

I'm testing it between 26850 and 30000 and this takes a couple minutes so 1 to 1 million would take far too long.

Thanks for any advice or suggestions!

Comment: Just do addition each step, no need to reselect (which makes an O(1) computation into an O(n) computation).

Comment: @Dops "It looks as though Team 1 always wins however there are certain cases this is not true." The observed effect of team 1 winning is called the Chebychev bias. Hardy and Littlewood have shown, however, that the "lead" changes infinitely often. More information here: Weisstein, Eric W. "Modular Prime Counting Function." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModularPrimeCountingFunction.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Improved Solution**

The challenge posed in the question is determine for any `x` up to `M = 1000000` whether `list1` or `list2` has more elements less than `x`.  The question suggests that `M` primes are needed to make that determination.  In fact, only the substantially smaller (by a factor of about `0.08`) set of primes less than or equal to `M` is needed.  It is computed by

```
M = 1000000;
listPrimes = Table[Prime[i], {i, 1, PrimePi[M]}];
list1 = Select[listPrimes, Mod[#1, 4] == 3 &];
list2 = Select[listPrimes, Mod[#1, 4] == 1 &];
```

Next, we count the number of primes less than any integer from `1` to `M`.

```
listm = Append[Prepend[list1, 1], M + 1];
count1 = Flatten@Table[ConstantArray[i - 1, listm[[i + 1]] - listm[[i]]], 
    {i, Length[listm] - 1}];
listm = Append[Prepend[list2, 1], M + 1];
count2 = Flatten@Table[ConstantArray[i - 1, listm[[i + 1]] - listm[[i]]], 
    {i, Length[listm] - 1}];
```

and `Tally` the number of instances that one or the other list is ahead.

```
Tally@MapThread[Sign[#1 - #2] &, {count1, count2}]
(* {{0, 1352}, {1, 995242}, {-1, 3406}} *)
```

`list1` is ahead for `995242` values of integer `x` between `1` and `M`, `list2` ahead for `3406` values of `x`, and the lists are tied for `1352` values of `x`.  The first ten `x`, for instance, at which `list2` is ahead is given by

```
Flatten@Position[MapThread[Sign[#1 - #2] &, {count1, count2}], -1][[1 ;; 10]]
(* {26861, 26862, 616841, 616842, 616849, 616850, 616851, 616852, 616853, 616854} *)
```

The `AbsoluteTiming` for this entire calculation is about 1.9 sec on my PC.

**Solution for M = 100000000**

My 8 GB PC can just barely handle `M = 100000000`, requiring about 200 sec and over 8.2 GB (some on disk).  Thus, run time varies linearly with `M`, as expected.  (Larger `M` could be handled by breaking the calculation into parts to reduce memory usage.)  The `Tally` results are

```
(* {{0, 3866}, {1, 99965510}, {-1, 30624}} *)
```

The `list2` "wins" are clustered into three groups, much as shown in the earlier plot below.

**Earlier Solution**

This earlier solution was derived for `1000000` primes.  It compares the magnitude of the nth prime of `list1` with that of `list2`.  Whichever list has the smaller prime is ahead at that point.  In effect, it involves sampling but nonetheless gives a good qualitative picture of the behavior of the race.

```
Count[MapThread[#1 < #2 &, {list1[[1 ;; Length[list2]]], list2}], False]
(* 1034 *)
```

Thus, there are 1034 instances among the first million primes in which a `list1` element is larger than the corresponding `list2` element.  The first one is readily found with

```
Position[MapThread[#1 < #2 &, {list1[[1 ;; Length[list2]]], list2}][[1 ;; 10000]], False]
(* {{1473}} *)

{list1[[%[[1, 1]]]], list2[[%[[1, 1]]]]}
(* {26863, 26861} *)
```

The distribution of rare cases can be plotted as follows.

```
ListPlot[{#, list1[[#]]} & /@ Flatten@Position[
    MapThread[#1 < #2 &, {list1[[1 ;; Length[list2]]], list2}], False], 
    PlotRange -> {{1, Length[list2]}, {1, list2[[-1]]}}]
```

[image]

So, the rare cases where a `list1` element is larger than the corresponding `list2` element are clustered into just three groups, the first barely visible near the origin.  Closer examination reveals that there is 1 case in the first cluster, about 150 cases in the second, and about 1330 in the third.

Comment: Hm very interesting.  I've never used MapThread and therefore don't really know what's going on however I'll try and pick it apart.  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: @Dops  `MapThread` is like `Map` but applies the function in its first argument to corresponding elements of multiple lists.

Comment: Could someone try and explain the syntax of what exactly is going?  Also do you mean "Thus, there are 1034 instances among the first million primes in which a list1 element is smaller than the corresponding list2 element."  I'm looking for when list 1 has less values than list 2.

Comment: @Dops  Does the additional material in my answer adequately address your comment just above?  My original answer looked at `x` equal to the primes in` list1`, whereas the more recent answer looks at all `x` up to `M`.  Although the qualitative behavior is similar, my newer answer is sufficiently fast that it ought to be the one used.

Answer (score 7):

The solution is fairly simple,

```
Prime[Sign@Accumulate[Mod[Prime@Range@PrimePi[1*^6],4]-2]~Position~-1]
```

where

- `Prime@Range@PrimePi[1*^6]` gives the list of all primes up to `1*^6`;
- `Mod[...,4]-2` automatically threads over the list above, giving `1` or `-1` for two teams respectively. Note that `Mod[2,4]-2` equals to `0`.
- `Sign@Accumulate[...]` gives a list of results about which team is leading so far.
- `Prime[...~Position~-1]` gives all primes team 2 is leading when up to which.

---

It takes 0.056s on my laptop to get the final result,

```
{{26861},{616841},{616849},...,{633653},{633667},{633797}}
```

---

**Other techniques**

Here are some techniques to improve performance, but be less elegant.

- `Mod[#,4]&  -->  BitAnd[#,3]&`
- `Position[#,-1]&  -->  Pick[Range@Length@#,#,-1]`; they are expressing the same idea in this case.

Comment: This is a very clever approach (+1), yielding a solution equivalent to my "Earlier Solution" but somewhat faster.  Do you see a similar approach that could reproduce my "Improved Solution" faster?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I do not think it will be faster since checking for every integers is actually much less efficient.